# Why is parent deleted when child is set to null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Say there is model that has a currency property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
    .HasOne<Currency>(p => p.Currency)
    .WithMany(q => q.Models)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

When the currency of a model is deleted, the model will be deleted as well. I am debugging an issue, where the model is deleted when currency is not deleted but just set to null:

```
var entity = await _dbContext.Models
    .Include(x => x.Currency)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id, cancellationToken);

entity.currency = await _dbContext.Currencies
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == currencyId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

So when I do `entity.currency = null` the model is deleted. Why is that?

Comment: Entity is a class with enumerable item for each table in the database (a property in the class).  So Currency is a table in the database.  The currency table has rows.  You are not deleting a row you are deleting the entire table.

Comment: @jdweng sorry, there was a typo in the relationship definition. Now it should be correct.

Comment: Why would that make any difference?  Check you entity classes to see if currency is a table (class) or a property in a table.  You may have a mapping issue between c# classes and the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is configured as optional, the default behavour of EF Core is to take no action in respect of the dependent entity if the principal is deleted. Consequently, if you delete the principal, any dependents will be left with foreign key values that reference principals that no longer exist. The default behaviour of a database is to raise an error in this scenario: foreign key values must reference existing primary key values.

You can alter this behaviour through the OnDelete method which takes a DeleteBehaviour enumeration. The following example sets the foreign key value of the dependent entity to null in the event that the principal is deleted.

You can follow through this [link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration)